# CSS Issues with word wrapping in an infiinite scrolling div

Tags: html, css

I am working on a project and want to have infinite horizontal scrolling for cells that each contain a thumbnail and some text.  I have everything mostly working.  However, I can not get text to wrap.  The css and html are below.  The first two items in the scroll box have text that should wrap, but overflows.

This is the style (cell 2 is only for demo to alternate background colors):

```css
 
        .container {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            padding: 10px;
            height: 10%;
            overflow-x: auto;
            white-space: nowrap;
    
            }
    
            .cell {
            background: #818181;
            flex: fit-content;
            padding: 10px;
            width: 220px;
            height: 8%;
            display: inline-block;
    
            }
    
            .cell2 {
            background: #f44336;
            flex: fit-content;
            padding: 10px;
            width: 220px;
            height: 8%;
            display: inline-block;
    
            }
    
            .data {
            justify-content: center;
            word-wrap: break-word;
            }
```

```html
         <div>
           <h2>Scroll Test</h2>
             <div class="container">
               <div class="cell">
                     <a href= "#">
                     <span class="data"> <img src="http://roncabeanz.com/Roncabeanz/images/CoffeeIcon.jpg" width="200px"></span>
                     <span class="data"> <h3>Some text here</h3></span>
                      </a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="cell2">
                      <a href= "#">
                        <span class="data"> <img src="http://roncabeanz.com/Roncabeanz/images/CoffeeIcon.jpg" width="200px"></span>
                        <span class="data"> <h3>Some text here that will over flow</h3></span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cell">
                        <a href= "#">
                            <span class="data"> <img src="http://roncabeanz.com/Roncabeanz/images/CoffeeIcon.jpg" width="200px"></span>
                            <span class="data"> <h3>Some text here</h3></span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cell2">
                        <a href= "#">
                            <div class="data"> <img src="http://roncabeanz.com/Roncabeanz/images/CoffeeIcon.jpg" width="200px">    </div>
                            <div class="data"> <h3>Some text here</h3></div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <?php } ?>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Link to fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jonathannah/3rxcktpm/29/

Comment: Do you mean the `h3`-text inside the first `.cell2`? In that case, it's because of the `white-space: nowrap` that gets inherited from your `.container` styles. Changing it to `white-space: normal` would fix that

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add
`h3 { white-space: normal }`. The children of `.container`inherit `white-space: nowrap`, which causes the problem. 
Another issue in your html is the `h3` inside a `span`, which is invalid. You shouldn't use block elements inside inline elements. You can change it to a `div` give it the style `display: inline`